Cosmological numerical computations
I am unsure where to ask this question, whether here or in the Mathematica stackexchange, but either way, I was wondering what are some recommendations for cosmological computations specifically using Mathematica, but I am open to using packages that require Python (which is what I use for computing correlation functions, but I'd like one for Mathematica). My main language skills are in Mathematica however.
My main goal is to compute the CMB power spectrum and specifically the polarization of the CMB and inflation correlators. My primary idea is that for some given action $S$, I can find the equations of motion on my own, maybe input the Fourier mode decomposition myself, and then let Mathematica take care of the rest.
For example, I have seen CMBquick which uses Mathematica which I'd prefer, but I was wondering if there are any other Mathematica packages used often (by theorists). I know there is CAMB (Python) and CMBeasy (C++) but I don't know those languages well (and I know no C at all).

I don't know those languages well (and I know no C at all FWIW, that is a problem that is easily remedied by trying

Also, this probably would be better suited for [mathematica.se] as (a) you're specifically looking for packages in that language and (b) software recommendations are generally considered off-topic here (cf. the tag info)

CAMB has some very nice documentation and the starting point is a set of python notebooks, which are very similar in spirit to Mathematica notebooks. In general, Python is a relatively easy programming language to get started with. It might be worth a shot and would give you some transferrable skills, if you aren't able to find an appropriate Mathematica notebook. https://camb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
